# How handle "missing message" error in react-intl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

I'm using react-intl version 2.4.0 and for some translations I receive  "missing message" error in console. Is there any way to handle them without upgrading to v3?

```
<IntlProvider
        locale="ru"
        messages={localeData.ru}
      >
        <Layout>
          <Component {...props} />
        </Layout>
      </IntlProvider>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'handle them'?

Comment: Without upgrading to v3 it would be a little tricky. Had you happened to look at this comment https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/issues/465#issuecomment-369566628

Comment: @BrettDeWoody do not show  error in console

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had not read that issue on GH, but if you scroll to the bottom you'll see there is now an [`onError` prop](https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/blob/master/docs/Components.md#intlprovider) (as of v2.7.1) to provide a custom error handler.

```
   <IntlProvider onError={myCustomErrorFunction} />
```

Provide your own error handler (without a `console.error`) and the console error should go away.

Comment: Link 'onError prop' has been udated

Comment: Updated link: https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/components#onerror