# Error: [@formatjs/intl Error MISSING_TRANSLATION] Missing message: "currentStage." for locale "he", using id as fallback

Tags: reactjs, django, error-handling, react-intl

so im trying to get data from DB, but i get this error and i dont know how to fix it.

[image: error]

this is where im fetching the data -
[image: data fetch]

this is where im trying to print it -
[image: print stage]

this is my he.json file constants -
[image: constants]

everything is printed but with error -
[image: print]

Comment: it would be better if you write your code in a code section and avoid using images, also the last part saying "everything is printed but with error -" the error is not written in english ..

Answer (score 0):

[How handle "missing message" error in react-intl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59388275/how-handle-missing-message-error-in-react-intl)

You can add your own custom function.You might be having a the id missing in the corresponding json.